# Edge for Business stuck on "setting up sync" when using on Linux enviroment in ChromeOS

Tags: linux, sync, microsoft-edge, chromebook, google-chrome-os

I'm using Edge for Business inside Linux environment installed on ChromeOS on my Acer Chromebook 315.

I've logged into my AAD Microsoft account by linking Edge to profile. The profile on AAD server has saved some history and some passwords. Unfortunately, the syncing process is stuck on "Setting up sync" stage.

I've tried unlinking the account, logging again, re-syncing, unlogging and removing profile with all local data from browser and logging again.

Nothing did help.

Maybe you could thing something sus from screenshot of my [image: edge://sync-internals] screen?

I see *Backed off* message and *Running* state in **Type Info** table. It looks to me like the syncing process is frozen somehow.